# How to select the 1st element of the column after splitting?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, split

I have the following data frame loaded in my jupyter notebook which is related to data scientist job description.

[image]

This is the output I got from lambda expression.

```
salary = df['Salary Estimate'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0])
```

[image]

How do I get the above result without using lambda? I tried the below code

```
salary = df['Salary Estimate'].str.split('(')[0]
```

but it gave me the following result

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.str[0]` for first values of each lists:

```
salary = df['Salary Estimate'].str.split('(').str[0]
```